# SOQL Knowledge Articles by Topic

Tags: soql, knowledge, topics

I have found from the docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_topics.htm&type=5) that you can enable Topics to

> classify and search articles by assigning topics.

Is it possible to utilize topics in SOQL? I'd like to do a query like this:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM KnowledgeArticles) FROM Topic WHERE Name LIKE :searchValue
```

Then I would return all the Ids from `KnowledgeArticles` to by custom lightning component that displays the search results.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to use "TopicAssignment".

Try this:

```
SELECT EntityType, EntityId, Topic.Name 
  FROM TopicAssignment 
 WHERE Topic.Name = 'Test' AND
       EntityType = 'Knowledge’
```